# RequireJS AMD component with non-AMD transitive dependency using bower

Tags: requirejs, dependencies, amd, bower

I am developing an AMD module that has a dependency that is defined in bower.  The app that consumes the module also has this dependency.  Is there a way to define the the dependency in the module's amd definition so that the application that uses the module doesn't have to name it the way the component expects?

the module's bower.json

```
{...
  "dependencies": {
    "my_module_dependency": "~1.2.21"
  }
}
```

the module definition which supports amd (but doesn't require it) mymodule.js:

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(function(require) {
      //this works only if the app that uses this module defines my_module_dependency in main.js
      var my_module_dependency = require("my_module_dependency");
      return (root.mymodule = factory(my_module_dependency));
    });
  } else {
    root.mymodule = factory(root.my_module_dependency);
  }
}(this, function(my_module_dependency) {
  ...
}
```

This works but it depends that the consuming application defines a requirejs dependency named "my_module_dependency" in it's main.js, but I want to be able to refer to it without forcing the consuming app to name it the way the component wants.

I know my module is a bower component, and my module's bower.json defines the my_module_dependency so I know where the dependency is relative to my component, but I am unable to have requirejs work with the relative path outside of my own component to refer to something the consuming app already has in it's requirejs dependency.

That is to say, the following doesn't work:

```
(function (root, factory) {
  if(typeof define === "function" && define.amd) {
    define(function(require) {
      //we know this will be here b/c it's a bower dep and so is this module
      var my_module_dependency = require("./bower_components/my_module_dependency");
      return (root.mymodule = factory(my_module_dependency));
    });
  } else {
    root.mymodule = factory(root.my_module_dependency);
  }
}(this, function(my_module_dependency) {
  ...
}
```

As expected there is only one call to retreive my_module_dependency since the consuming app already required it (if I were to misspell it I would see the consuming app load the correct version then my component try to load the misspelled resource and get a 404).  There are no immediate console errors but then after a second or two this error shows:

```
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: bower_components/angular/angular
  http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout require.js:166
  makeError require.js:166
  checkLoaded require.js:692
  (anonymous function)
```

Also, I need the consuming app and the component to be using the same instance of my_module_dependency.

Any guesses?